# vimperator alphanumeric hints

Tags: firefox, vimperator

Vimperator uses strictly numeric hints by default. This has several disadvantages:

- Smaller scope: it only takes 10 links to get to double digits
- Number keys are harder to type

Is there any way to make Vimperator use more characters (ideally `[a-zA-Z0-9]`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an option called hintchars, that changes the characters that are used for hints.

You have put the following line in your .vimperatorrc, of course with exactly the characters on the right hand side that you want to use:

set hintchars=asdfghklqwertyuiop

Comment: Thanks, although it's case insensitive.

Answer (score 3):

To add to answer above. If you type `set hintchars=` you'll get a nice list of recommendations
[image]

You can set the values to pretty much any keys though just remember that the order matters and the hints will start in that order so `Smart Order` is pretty awesome.

If you prefer more characters you can make it case sensitive by setting it to:
`hjklHJKL...` so first 8 links will always be at your fingertips !